# Array to use for appending unknown number of bytes into single large array in System verilog

Tags: arrays, system-verilog

I am trying to append unknown number of bytes into a single large array . Which array type should I use ? I am trying to this

```
      len=temp_i.len()
      for(i=0;i<len;i++)begin
      bit [7:0] temp_ascii;
      temp_ascii=temp_i.getc(i);
      arr = {arr,temp_ascii};
```

where temp_i is an input srting. My Final aim is convert input String into binary representation of its ASCII value and concatenate them together into a single large array. 
I having a hard time choosing what kind of array to use dynamic or associative or if I can use queue.

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You use associative arrays when the index values are not consecutive, or the ordering is meaningless. Not applicable here.

You use queues when adding or removing one element at a time to an array. If `arr` was declared as a queue, you could write

```
string temp_i;
bit [7:0] arr[$];
int len;

len = temp_i.len();
for(int i=0,i<len;i++) 
  arr.push_back(temp_i.getc(i));
```

If your strings are small, or you plan to concatenate many strings together, a queue is your best option. But if you only plan to convert one string to an array, then using a bit-stream cast to a dynamic array will be the most efficient.

```
string temp_i;
typedef bit [7:0] uint8_da_t[]; // typedef required for cast to target
uint8_da_t arr; // using typedef not required here, but A VERY GOOD IDEA

arr = uint8_da_t'(temp_i);
```

Comment: I need to convert one string into an large array. Where I can append more bits to it. For example, temp_i="AB CD WE" . I need to convert it into it's equivalent ASCII value and append certain bits to it using some calculation.       
         I tried using bit stream cast but it's throwing an error "Feature is not yet supported: string casting of unsupported type".

Answer (score 0):

is it supposed to be a synthesizable code or a test bench?
None of the above is synthesizable.

you would do it differently in different worlds.

Comment: It's a task in my testbench.

Comment: then you could use dynamic arrays, as Dave suggested. There is no much choice in verilog for this kind of operations. If you are in system verilog, you can use dpi calls to 'c' and do it in 'c'.

Comment: Yeah I am doing in system verilog.

Comment: yeah, you definitely are. apologies :-)